# Lazy loading angularjs 1.8 controllers in routeprovider using ES6 import()

Tags: angularjs, ecmascript-6, import

In my angularjs 1.8 routeprovider, I'm currently lazy loading controllers and css files for a given view by using ocLazyLoad, however I want to try using ES6 import/export modules to keep code tidier and enable automatic importing of dependencies.

In my resolver for each .when route case, lazy loaded scripts work as-is for controllers and their dependencies, but if I switch to using the import syntax, lazy loading no longer works (the first error will be that the javascript import statements can only be at the top level of a module, which is understandable).

I've tried returning a promise that waits for all import modules' promises to finish using the following. While the scripts load, angularjs complains about the controller not existing (the routes use the named controllers and the imported scripts inject the controller into the app). I presume this is because the routeprovider tries to assign the controller name before it has loaded, even though it's waiting for the scripts to load via the promises before rendering.

```
loadModules: [function () {
return Promise.all(options.modules.map(module => import(module) ));
}]
```

I have also tried automatically determining the exports primary module and registering the controller in the resolver (with the controller exported as `[dependencies, function(){}]` ), instead of adding it to the app in the script, but it has the same effect:

```
loadModules: ['$controllerProvider', function ($controllerProvider) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

        // Create a promise that returns the result of all the import module promises
        return import(options.module).then(function (mod) {
            let firstProp = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(mod)[0];
            console.log('module load', firstProp)
            if (!$controllerProvider.has(firstProp)) {
                $controllerProvider.register(firstProp, mod[firstProp]);
                console.log('registered', firstProp);
            }
            resolve();
        });
    });
}],
```

So, my question is, has anyone got ES6 import syntax to work with the routeprovider for lazy loading?